# Translate uiview in direction of touch moved, iphone

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to translate `UIView` in same direction as touch moves .

Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488823/move-uiview-with-relation-to-touch

Answer (score 3):

Modify the touchesBegan and touchesMoved methods to be like the following

```
float oldX, oldY;
BOOL dragging;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(window.frame, touchLocation)) {

        dragging = YES;
        oldX = touchLocation.x;
        oldY = touchLocation.y;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (dragging) {

        CGRect frame = window.frame;
        frame.origin.x = window.frame.origin.x + touchLocation.x - oldX;
        frame.origin.y =  window.frame.origin.y + touchLocation.y - oldY;
        window.frame = frame;
    }

    oldX = touchLocation.x;
    oldY = touchLocation.y;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    dragging = NO;
}
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like the code below. I'm not sure if it is a best solution for all direction translation.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if ([touches count] != 1) return;

  _swipeStartInX = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x;
  _swipeStartInY = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y;
  _swiping = YES;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (!_swiping || [touches count] != 1) return;

  CGFloat swipeDistanceInX = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x - _swipeStartInX;
  CGFloat swipeDistanceInY = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y - _swipeStartInY;
  CGSize contentSize = self.frame.size;

  [_yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(swipeDistanceInX - contentSize.width, swipeDistanceInY - contentSize.width, contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (!_swiping) return;

  // You can set the last position when touches end.
  // E.g. You can set positions like slide page does, just the the origin of _yourView.
}
```

If you just want translate in vertical and horizontal direction, you can use `UIScrolView` instead. :)

Comment: Thanks Kjuly , but it is not working perfectly .when i translate uiview through touch then uiiview becomes blurred and not moving in same direction as in touch moves.

Comment: @agrawalamit31 I have a test app on github, it may be helpful: [https://github.com/Kjuly/ios-exploration/blob/master/EffectPicSlide/EffectPicSlide/SlideView.m](https://github.com/Kjuly/ios-exploration/blob/master/EffectPicSlide/EffectPicSlide/SlideView.m). It run as what `slide view page` does. You can modify the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` to meet your requirement. :)

Comment: @agrawalamit31, by the way, it just handle the horizontal direction. But you can handle the vertical direction in the same way. ;)

Comment: Thanks Kjuly for giving attention to my problem but i want to move uiview in direction of touch (may be horizontal, vertical ,clockwise translation and anticlockwise translation).

Comment: @agrawalamit31 clockwise translation? Mum, that's a question. Maybe you need a algorithm to do rotation. Best wishes! :D

Comment: Thanks Kjuly . i do not need rotation but i want to move uiview in same way as my touch moves in curavature form so that it can look interactive

Comment: @agrawalamit31 if you want to move a small UIView as a character, the [link](https://github.com/Kjuly/ios-exploration/blob/master/EffectPicSlide/EffectPicSlide/SlideView.m) i gave will help. If you need to move a big view(like a big picture show in your phone window), you can use `UIScrollView`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this method to your subclassed *UIView* class.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previousLocation= [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    CGFloat deltaX = currentLocation.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat deltaY = currentLocation.y - previousLocation.y;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + deltaX, self.frame.origin.y + deltaY, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}
```