# Trouble with touch move

Tags: ios, shake, touchmove

I want to make sure that the motion moved with the button held down picture (as in some trategiyah). But the image shake when I move it. Here's the code:

```
// PROPERTY
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *gameView;

@property GameState gameState; // for current state == Game
@property CGPoint touchPoint;
@property CGPoint screenOffset;

// INICIALIZE
_gameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_gameView.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:iname] drawInRect:_gameView.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

_gameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
_gameView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubview:_gameView];

// METHODS
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    switch (_gameState) {
        case Start:
            break;

        case Game:
            if ([touch view] == _gameView) {
                _touchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
                NSLog(@"startTouch");
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    switch (_gameState) {
        case Start:
            break;

        case Game:
            if ([touch view] == _gameView) {
                NSLog(@"%f%f", [touch locationInView:touch.view].x, [touch locationInView:touch.view].y);

                currentTouchPoint.x += _screenOffset.x - _touchPoint.x;
                currentTouchPoint.y += _screenOffset.y - _touchPoint.y;

                _gameView.center = currentTouchPoint;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint endedTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    switch (_gameState) {
        case Start:
            break;

        case Game:
            if ([touch view] == _gameView) {
                _screenOffset.x += endedTouchPoint.x - _touchPoint.x;
                _screenOffset.y += endedTouchPoint.y - _touchPoint.y;

                _gameView.center = _screenOffset;
                NSLog(@"endTouch");
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Even if slightly moving the mouse - the image jumps. Here is what appears in the log:

```
startTouch
206.000000    319.000000
206.000000    338.000000
209.000000    342.000000
211.000000    367.000000
217.000000    393.000000
228.000000    435.000000
291.000000    580.000000
244.000000    470.000000
316.000000    620.000000
250.000000    470.000000
330.000000    620.000000
263.000000    468.000000
...
endTouch
```

At the same time I moved the pointer one direction. Where mistake?

I not want to move all objects. 
I find reason. If write:

```
_gameView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"field1.png"]];
_gameView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
//_gameView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

that's work, but if uncomment last string problem return. But it needs for my program =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure the location of the touch is given in coordinates of AddView's parent view with the line:

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:AddView.superview];
```

Comment: I replace UIView *gameView to UIImageView *gameView and it worked. But why not work with UIView?

Comment: and how I can check condition ([touch view] == gameView)?

Comment: You are moving the entire window, which contains all the views, you should only move the view you want.

Comment: check out this link may it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488823/move-uiview-with-relation-to-touch?rq=1